# Why is my custom API endpoint not working?

Tags: rest-api, endpoints

I tried to include this code in my plug-in php files as well as in `functions.php`.
(In the end I would like it to be in the plug-in's php file but I'm not yet sure if possible, that would probably be the topic of another question.)

It is a very basic method for now, I'm just trying to get a response with some content.

In both cases, I get a 404 response.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( plugin_dir_url(__DIR__).'my-project/api/v1/form', '/action', array(
    'methods' => 'GET, POST',
    'callback' => 'api_method',
  ) );
});

function api_method($data) {
    var_dump($data);
    return 'API method end.';
}
```

And I tried to access URLs (in brower or with AJAX)

- http://my-domain.local/wp-content/plugins/my-project/api/v1/form
- http://my-domain.local/wp-content/plugins/my-project/api/v1/form/
- http://my-domain.local/wp-content/plugins/my-project/api/v1/form/get
- http://my-domain.local/wp-content/plugins/my-project/api/v1/form/get/

I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: Rest API endpoints live at `/wp-json`, to include `plugin_dir_url` in your endpoint registration is **extremely unusual**, I would strongly recommend against REST endpoint URLs in the plugins folder ( mostly because that's not how the API works, you can't have those kinds of URLs )

Comment: @TomJNowell – Can you see why this question got so many views in such a short time? Should I ask this on Meta?

Comment: asking on meta is a good idea, I'm not sure how we can see views though. Maybe your question was well written and popular? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe start with just `GET`. Your route looks weird as well. Try just:

```
register_rest_route('my-project/v1', '/action/', [
  'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
  'callback' => 'api_method',
]);
```

---

And your callback is not returning a valid response. Let your callback look more like this:

```
$data = [ 'foo' => 'bar' ];

$response = new WP_REST_Response($data, 200);

// Set headers.
$response->set_headers([ 'Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store, private' ]);

return $response;
```

---

Finally you must combine `wp-json`, the namespace `my-project/v1` and your route `action` to the URL you now can check for what you get:

```
 https://my-domain.local/wp-json/my-project/v1/action
```

Comment: I just followed what you suggested, tried http://my-domain.local/my-project/v1/ , http://my-domain.local/my-project/v1/get/ (with and without trailing slashes), still getting 404 response. At the moment, the code is in functions.php.

Comment: @TTT – It must be https://my-domain.local/wp-json/my-project/v1/action as you've specified `/action/` to be your route.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Well since the answer is in the comment, I not sure if I should check the answer as solution right away.

Also, I can make this return something else than JSON, right ? (I mean not like XML, like php processed HTML code.) ... Then the URL would still contain "wp-json". Weird ... or is there another type of API?

Comment: @TTT you can store HTML in JSON as a string then JSON decode in the browser

Comment: I just found and tested this way here that looks cleaned than including HTML in JSON: https://gist.github.com/petenelson/6dc1a405a6e7627b4834

Comment: @TTT – Uh nice! Thanks for sharing. Bookmarked.

Answer (score 5):

Here's your problem:

```
register_rest_route( plugin_dir_url(__DIR__).'my-project/api/v1/form', '/action', array(
```

Specifically the idea that this is possible:

```
http://my-domain.local/wp-content/plugins/my-project/api/v1/form
```

This is extremely unusual, and runs counter to what's in the docs, handbook, and tutorials.

REST API endpoints live at the REST API, which lives at the URL returned by `rest_url()`. They live at `yoursite.com/wp-json`. An endpoint is not a full URL path, or an independent API disconnected from the main API.

Instead, you need to define your endpoint names in terms of namespaces and endpoints, and visit the correct URL as described in the REST API's discovery mechanisms.

If we use this:

```
register_rest_route( plugin_dir_url(__DIR__).'my-project/api/v1/form', '/action', array(
```

Then we would expect this:

`example.com/wp-json/wp-content/plugins/my-project/api/v1/form/action`

That URL is quite long, and has a number of problems:

- **The first parameter is a namespace, not a URL**
- it's not possible to correctly separate out v1 of the API from v2 due to the way that that `/form` component has been put in the first parameter, not the second. The first parameter is a namespace, the second a route
- `/action` is `/action`, it doesn't get swapped out for `GET` OR `POST`

There are also problems with the callback function:

```
function api_method($data) {
    var_dump($data);
```

An endpoint needs to return its data, it cannot output it directly as `var_dump` would, otherwise the returned data is invalid JSON.

Finally, the methods parameter is incorrect:

```
'methods' => 'GET, POST',
```

`methods` doesn't take a comma separated list, no docs suggest doing this either. Instead, use the predefined values provided by the REST API such as `WP_REST_Server::READABLE` or `WP_REST_Server::ALLMETHODS`, these are all mentioned in the handbook and the official documentation for `register_rest_route`.

A better route to register would be:

```
    register_rest_route( 'my-project/form/v1', '/action', array(
```

Giving us:

`example.com/wp-json/my-project/form/v1/action`

Notice how I removed the plugin URL and the redundant `/api` fragment ( it's obvious it's an API already )

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. I've already marked an answer that came quicker as solution however.

Comment: You can change your mind about which answer is best, but eitherway think of the site as a wiki, there can be more than 1 good answer

Comment: One reason why I don't want to change answer is that I have conretely tested and applied the answer I selected as solution. Your answer brought more details and things I had thought in a wrong way somehow, but I haven't litteraly tested  and checked it all.

I also think that on most StackExchange sites, first good answers get selected, next one get votes. And though this has me scratching my head a bit, I see no reason to remove the solution rewards from the person who solved it first.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, just add this **wp-json** in the url of the webhook sender, what will result in

`https://my-domain.local/wp-json/my-plugin/v1/action`

and in my **functions.php** thoses lines of code work

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_webhook_endpoint');

function register_webhook_endpoint() {
  register_rest_route('my-plugin/v1', '/action', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'handle_webhook_request',
  ));
}

function handle_webhook_request(WP_REST_Request $request) {
  // Process the webhook request
  $data = $request->get_body(); // Get the request body
  // Perform actions based on the received webhook data

  // Return a response if needed
  return new WP_REST_Response('Webhook received.', 200);
}
```